# Is Google OR Tools TSP parallel by default?

Tags: or-tools

I use the [routing library](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing) a lot and am wondering if OR Tools uses all available cores on a particular machine by default. For example, when solving an integer program in Gurobi, it shows the number of cores available and the number of threads it uses automatically. How can we find that out when using the routing functions in Google OR Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. TSP is sequential.

CP-SAT is parallel by default.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? I thought TSP in OR-Tools uses CP-SAT under the hood.

Comment: Yes, but only as a sub solver. The driver is the original CP solver.